# Passing address of Container equivalent to OutputIterator?

Tags: c++, cgal

Section 1.3.2 [here](http://www.cgal.org/Manual/3.4/doc_html/cgal_manual/Introduction/Chapter_main.html) in CGAL documentation argues to use `OutputIterator` for returning the result of `convex_hull_2()` because container is empty at the time of call so we cannot pass `result.begin()`.

In a sample non-CGAL program, I tried to simply pass the address of empty container as an output argument to a function(which adds some elements to the container) and I was able access the elements back in the caller.

So I would like to know whether passing address of a container is *always* equivalent to passing an `OutputIterator` to that container? If it is so, then are there any *other* specific reasons to introduce `OutputIterators` in CGAL functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The advantage of `OutputIterator` is that you can make templates that can take any type of standard container. Another advantage compared to passing an address or a reference is that caller may choose to use to use either `std::front_inserter` or `std::back_inserter` depending on what order they want and which is faster/possible for their chosen container. The caller may even extend the functionality of the function with the use of a custom iterator.

Here is how you pass an `OutputIterator` to an empty container:

```
template<class Iter>
void foo(Iter it) {}

std::list<int> bar;
foo(std::inserter(bar, bar.begin()));
```

It's okay to call `begin()` on an empty container as long as the returned iterator is not dereferenced.

The reason that begin cannot simply be passed is because begin is not an `OutputIterator`.

Comment: Regarding "...you can make templates that can take any type of standard container...", can't we still achieve this using passing by reference approach as `template<class T> void foo(T a)` and in caller by `std::list<int>bar; foo(&bar);` ?

Comment: @Pranav, how would you insert into `T`?

Comment: Hint: Standard containers are not guaranteed/required to have `push_back` (`std::forward_list` doesn't) or `push_front` (`std::vector` doesn't) methods.

Comment: Ok I got it. At the time I posted the code I had not seen your recent comment. So I have deleted the code now, since in that I implicitly assumed that container will support push_back().